# Trajectory relative to position of a gameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image] How can I make the trajectory of a gameObject depend on the position of another gameObject in Unity as illustrated in the following link?

http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/6900/vu6.gif

Answer (score 1):

Code for that example gif is from here, would that work?
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/generating-dynamic-parabola.211681/#post-1426150